why kafka will temporarily add replicas when the partition is expanded
In kafka 2.6.1, there is a topic called test with two copies and 30 partitions. Now the partitions are expanded to 40. However, it is found that the disk capacity changes during the expansion process. After looking at the topic, it is found that there are the original 30 partitions. From two copies to three copies, why is this? What is the mechanism?
enter image description here
Just give me an idea

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"Under the covers, when Kafka moves a partition, it will add a new replica on the destination machine as a follower of the partition it is migrating. The new replica is allowed to replicate and when it is fully caught up, it will be marked as in-sync. Then one of the existing replicas on the original server will be deleted, completing the move."
See the Confluent documentation
